# Google calendar PHP API time issue

Tags: google-calendar-api

I was playing with [Google calendar's API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/) and managed to get the events list from my calendar. And i managed to insert some events into the calendar from API explorer. But im confused with the time property.

When i inserted an event from explorer, i wanted event time to be from 10:00 to 10:30. So i put as following:

```
{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2018-07-12T10:30:00.0z"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2018-07-12T10:00:00.0z"
 }
}
```

Insertion was successful. But when i checked the calendar, its showing that event's time as 03:00-03:30. Date is correct. What I want is, if I insert 10:00 as start time it should be inserted as 10:00 irrespective of time zones and if I insert 10:30 as end time it should show 10:30.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you clarify "10:00 irrespective of time zones"? If you set the timezone to your own, people from other timezone will follow the time in respect of the timezone you have set.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I mean is, suppose I have to start a sale at "10:00am" IST(Indian Standard Time), so If I create an event at 10:00am IST, it will show 10:00am for all other time zones also. I do not want to change the time based on TZ. Meaning, If 10:00am IST is 02:00pm for New Zealand than I don't want that. I want is it will show 10:00am for New Zeland also.

Comment: In short, show what is created. Do not change the time based on TZ.

Comment: Perhaps you can just insert all your events in UTC then...worth a try, I haven't got time to test that right now, but perhaps you can. Trouble is what the end-user sees may depend on how their _client_ is set up to deal with timezones. But...why do you want a new zealand user to think the sale is at 10am when in fact, for them, it's at 2am? It sounds like it would just have the potential to create confusion?

Comment: @ADyson I will give UTC a try and see if that works for me. On the other thing regarding creating confusion, my clients wants it that way.

Comment: In that case have you considered asking your clients why they want it that way, and mentioning the potential for it to be confusing? Our job as developers is not always simply to implement everything the client wants without question, sometimes we have to point out to them if we think a requirement is unwise, risky, or impossible - or just very expensive! In this case if they decide they have made a mistake, it's an advantage for you, because you don't have to make a workaround to deal with an unusual scenario.

Comment: @ADyson you are 100% percent correct and I totally agree with you. But sometimes clients get offended as in my scenario. They want it the way the asked to develop. But still I will try and explain my client about the confusion it may create. Thank you so much. I will update you once I had a conversation with him.